# Android Emulator is not running on Xamarin Forms. Build cancelled everytime i run VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I run my project on Android Emulator and it doesn't run by showing message Build Cancelled. Although project is running correct on UWP and my mobile phone

Comment: share the log file, **Help > Xamarin > Open Logs**

Comment: Post your logs, environments and sample here.

Answer (score 0):

Apps & Features > Programs & Features > Turns Windows features on or off

Scroll down til you find Windows Hypervisor platform, and enable it

Go into your bios and enable VTx

Done.